# Send Apache Camel Actuator Metrics to Prometheus

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-camel, prometheus

I am trying to forward/add the Actuator Camel metrics from `/actuator/camelroutes` (route metrics like number of exchanges/transactions) to the Prometheus Actuator endpoint. Is there a way for me to configure Camel to add those metrics to the PrometheusMeterRegistry?

I have tried adding:

```
camel.component.metrics.metric-registry=io.micrometer.prometheus.PrometheusMeterRegistry
```

in my `application.properties` according to the documentation here: https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/metrics-component.html

But still nothing relating to Apache Camel is displayed in `actuator/prometheus`

Here are the dependencies I am using with **Spring Boot 2.1.9** and **Apache Camel 2.24.2**:

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-metrics-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
            <artifactId>micrometer-registry-prometheus</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Got the Camel Routes metrics working in the `/actuator/prometheus` endpoint.

Use the **camel-micrometer-starter** dependency as stated by @claus-ibsen 's comment.

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-metrics-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Set the following in your properties file:

```
camel.component.metrics.metric-registry=prometheusMeterRegistry
```

Then add set the Camel Context to use the MicrometerRouterPolicyFactory and MicrometerMessageHistoryFactory. Code seen below is places in a Configuration class:

```java
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    public CamelContextConfiguration camelContextConfiguration() {

        return new CamelContextConfiguration() {
            @Override
            public void beforeApplicationStart(CamelContext camelContext) {
                camelContext.addRoutePolicyFactory(new MicrometerRoutePolicyFactory());
                camelContext.setMessageHistoryFactory(new MicrometerMessageHistoryFactory());
            }

            @Override
            public void afterApplicationStart(CamelContext camelContext) {

            }
        };
    }

}
```

You need to trigger an exchange in a route for the metrics to appear in `/actuator/prometheus`.

Here are the metrics made available to Prometheus:

1. CamelMessageHistory_seconds_count
2. CamelMessageHistory_seconds_max
3. CamelRoutePolicy_seconds_max
4. CamelRoutePolicy_seconds_count
5. CamelRoutePolicy_seconds_sum

**You can use the JMX Exporter jar for Prometheus to get the more detailed metrics from the JMX of Camel.** I wanted to avoid this approach as it would mean that for each Camel Spring Boot App I have would use 2 ports; 1 for the JMX Metrics and 1 for the Actuator Metrics.

Comment: Im trying to implement this as well and thanks for your post, i was able to see the above metrics that you posted. just wondering, in your implementation, are these the only camel metrics that you're monitoring? Were you able to implement your own PrometheusMeterRegistry bean?

Comment: can you please share the pom dependency for MicrometerRouterPolicyFactory and MicrometerMessageHistoryFactory.

Comment: @prashant.kr.mod it is `<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-micrometer</artifactId>
</dependency>`

Comment: Note that you also need to enable the prometheus endpoint in your application properties:
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include: camelroutes,prometheus,etc

I also had to add:

<dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
            <artifactId>micrometer-registry-prometheus</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

To pom.xml

Answer (score 1):

There is a `camel-micrometer-starter` dependency you should use instead that integrates with micrometer. And then you can use the micrometer route policy from that dependency to let it monitor all your routes. See the docs at: https://camel.apache.org/components/2.x/micrometer-component.html

Comment: I have added this but I am having a problem having the Camel metrics appear in the `/actutator/prometheus` page. I have tried setting `camel.component.micrometer.metrics-registry` to `metricsRegistry`, `io.micrometer.prometheus.PrometheusRegistry`and `prometheusRegistry` but still no go. Do I need to define a bean in a configuration class for the metrics to appear in Prometheus Actuator endpoint?

Comment: I tried adding this to my configuration class but the `/actuator/prometheus` page bacame blank: ```@Bean(MicrometerConstants.METRICS_REGISTRY_NAME)
 public PrometheusMeterRegistry meterRegistry() {
  return new PrometheusMeterRegistry(PrometheusConfig.DEFAULT);
 }```

Comment: I tried setting `camel.component.micrometer.metrics-registry=prometheusMeterRegistry` and got the Prometheus Actuator endpoint working again but nothing seems to be added relating to Camel.

Comment: You also need the route policy factory to have it monitor the Camel routes

Comment: Added my config class but still no change: `@Bean
    public CamelContextConfiguration contextConfiguration() {
        return new CamelContextConfiguration() {
            @Override
            public void beforeApplicationStart(CamelContext camelContext) {
                camelContext.addRoutePolicyFactory(new MicrometerRoutePolicyFactory());
                camelContext.setMessageHistoryFactory(new MicrometerMessageHistoryFactory());
            }

            @Override
            public void afterApplicationStart(CamelContext camelContext) {

            }
        };
    }`

Answer (score 0):

I can see the metrics by keeping these dependencies intact

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
  <artifactId>camel-management</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
  <artifactId>camel-metrics</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
  <artifactId>camel-micrometer-starter</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
  <artifactId>micrometer-registry-prometheus</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Why dont I see the actual process and bean names rather than like process3, bean1 etc ??

```
    CamelMessageHistory_seconds_sum{camelContext="AppName",nodeId="process3",routeId="AppNameRoute",serviceName="MicrometerMessageHistoryService",} 0.041466
    CamelMessageHistory_seconds_count{camelContext="AppName",nodeId="bean1",routeId="AppNameRoute",serviceName="MicrometerMessageHistoryService",} 100.0
    CamelMessageHistory_seconds_sum{camelContext="AppName",nodeId="bean1",routeId="AppNameRoute",serviceName="MicrometerMessageHistoryService",} 4.8417576
```

Answer (score 0):

I am currently working with Apache Camel and using the Micrometer component for metrics. I have added the necessary dependency, but I am facing an issue where the metric is not showing up in the /actuator/prometheus endpoint.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).