# How to output Apache Camel metrics like metrics:timer:simple.timer to Prometheus using Micrometer format with /actuator/prometheus

Tags: java, apache-camel, spring-boot-actuator, spring-camel, spring-micrometer

Based on the [Camel's metrics documentation](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/micrometer-component.html#MicrometerComponent-timer), I'd like to meter 2 different timers within one route:

```
  @Override
    public void configure() {
        from(
                getMqttRouteConfiguration(
                        sourceId, mqttHost, mqttTopic, mqttPort, mqttProtocol, authenticated,
                        username, password, mqttVersion, maxReadRate, qualityOfService
                )
        )
                .to("metrics:timer:simple.timer1?action=start") //here starts the first one
                .to("log:camel.proxy?level=INFO&groupInterval=500000")
                .to("metrics:counter:simple.counter")
                .to(String.format("kafka:%s?brokers=%s", sourceId, kafkaBrokerUrls))
                .to("metrics:timer:simple.timer1?action=stop") //here ends the first one
                .to("metrics:timer:simple.timer2?action=start") //here starts the second one
                .process(new Processor() {
                    @Override
                    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                        exchange.getIn().setBody(exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class));
                        exchange.getIn().setHeader("CamelCacheKey", sourceId);
                        exchange.getIn().setHeader("CamelCacheOperation", "Update");
                    }
                })
                .to(String.format("cache://%s?maxElementsInMemory=10&eternal=true", sourceId))
                .to("metrics:timer:simple.timer2?action=stop") //here ends the second one
                .routeId(sourceId);
    }
```

i.e. take 2 timers from two different parts of route instead of the whole route statistics like

```
CamelRoutePolicy_seconds_count{camelContext="camel-1",failed="false",routeId="ESP_01.Handle_Movement",serviceName="MicrometerRoutePolicyService",} 137.0
CamelRoutePolicy_seconds_sum{camelContext="camel-1",failed="false",routeId="ESP_01.Handle_Movement",serviceName="MicrometerRoutePolicyService",} 1.200024598
```

as it is calculated automatically for the whole route. The set up of Micrometer format metrics output to `/actuator/prometheus` for obtaining the `CamelRoutePolicy_seconds_` is taken from this question: [Send Apache Camel Actuator Metrics to Prometheus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58536192/send-apache-camel-actuator-metrics-to-prometheus)

However, my expectation was that the custome metrics `metrics:timer:simple.timer2`, `metrics:timer:simple.timer1` will be also here and shown among the `CamelRoutePolicy_seconds_`

But it is not there. What I should set up in order to get it too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, the long story short: Apache Camel's [Metrics](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/metrics-component.html) component is not the same as [Micrometer](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/micrometer-component.html)

I was needed the Micrometer. So, in all routes I had to replace `metrics:` with `micrometer:` and everything has worked. Please also consider that dependencies (looks like both are needed):

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-micrometer-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-micrometer</artifactId>
        <version>${camel.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```